# Visual studio mistakes valid code as invalid after debug edit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, unity-container

I am using visual studio 2013 with unity 3.5 downloaded using nuget. I have Container class that looks like the following

```
  public class Container
  {
    static IUnityContainer _container; //<- System IDisposable error on _container
    static ILogger _logger = GetLogger();

    //continuation here
  }
```

My problem is when I execute the application, debug runs fine, but if I edited a statement completely unrelated to the class above during debug process, when I resume debugging I get the following strange error with blue underline below `_container`!!

[image]

> The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

after this I will have to stop debug and restart again. without touching anything the error disappears and can debug back.

I looked for System.Runtime assembly in Framework assemblies but I could not find it. the available assemblies are:

> System.Runtime.caching 
>   System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
>   System.Runtime.Remoting
>   System.Runtime.Serialization
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap

any way how to at least track down this error?

Comment: Is editing code while debugging really that great an idea anyway?  It seems to only work in limited scenarios, and I would imagine using depency injection wouldn't be one of them....

Comment: @DanField I can't agree with you because I find it very useful in many situations, I would like to ask why you think it isn't but that would be another subject.

Comment: It can be useful, but if you're using it exensively you may want to look at creating some unit tests - I realize that's not an answer to your question, but if it turns out you just can't do what you're trying to do, a suite of unit tests would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @MusuNaji: it is useful, but it simply can't work in all circumstances, simply because by performing an edit, some state long ago in your program can now be unreachable. Even "completely unrelated" edits can have side effects because a compiler/IDE always must be conservative...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. Actually I was debugging some unit tests which I didn't know why they failed and had to edit some code. Anyway, I unfortunately still can't fix this issue, I wonder what that System.Runtime assembly is, I can't find it in framework assemblies though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

There is a `system.runtime.dll` in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\` I added a reference to it and it solved the problem. I don't know if this the right thing to do but at least the IDisposable error disappeared.
I wonder why this assembly is not listed in standard assemblies list.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this same problem (though I didn't need to edit while debugging to trigger it). For me, it turned out that the (false) error messages were actually being generated by Resharper rather than Visual Studio. I was able to confirm this by doing `Tools | Options | Resharper | Suspend Now`; all the little red squiggles instantly went away. With that clue in hand, I was able to discover [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427743#tab=Comments); which shows this is a known issue with Resharper 9.0. The fix will be included in version 9.2, which appears to be scheduled for August. If you're impatient like me, you can get the fix now by installing the latest EAP (early access preview) from [this location](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.2+EAP).